# Use Instruments to detect why UI is un responsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, instruments

I have build an iOS app that allows sharing to facebook and twitter.

I present my SLComposeViewController the same way for Facebook and Twitter messages using

```
presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil
```

this works fine. After sharing to facebook the app is responsive and works, after successfully posting to twitter the app becomes unresponsive but no exceptions are thrown.

Can I use instruments to find out what is causing this? or what is in the Main Queue? etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use the Timer Profiler feature to examine what portion of your program is tying up the CPU.

See [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments/) for details.

Comment: Thanks, that tutorial helped, I created an infinite loop and you can see the effect. It appears nothing is running to cause the interface to hang. No idea why it is doing it then. :(

Comment: There no spike in CPU usage during the hang?